# NESTJS error "ENOENT" breaking the API server

Tags: node.js, rest, file, nestjs

I Have a route in my NESTJS Node API server to get files, however when there's no File specified on the path, I recieve the error :

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '(the path specified)'

After the error occurs my server stop working and I have to restart the process again with "nest start".

How do I catch this error, and return it to the request, instead of just breaking the API?

The code:

```
try {
  const file = createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), filesrc.path));

  res.set({
    "Content-Type": `${filesrc.type}`,
    "Content-Disposition": `attachment;filename="${filesrc.original_name}"`,
    "Content-Length": +filesrc.size
  })
  res.status(200);
  return new StreamableFile(file);
} catch (err) {
  throw new HttpException('test', 500)
}
```

Note: the "filesrc" is the variable that holds some file information.

Comment: What's your `@nestjs/common` version? I could've sworn I fixed this to return an error but not crash the server

Comment: @jay-mcdoniel The version used in this project is "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0"

Comment: There's a fix on version 9 that stops the server from crashing

Comment: That's great, ill try to update the version and return if it fixed for me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Solutions that I Found:

#1 (Recommended) as  Jay McDoniel suggested, upgrade NestJS to latest version, version 9 fixes the issue.

#2 (If you can't upgrade your NestJs, my case) you can check if the file exists first using Node's fs 'existSync' function

```
 try {
  if (fs.existsSync(filesrc.path)) {
    const file = createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), filesrc.path));
    res.set({
      "Content-Type": `${filesrc.type}`,
      "Content-Disposition": `attachment;filename="${filesrc.original_name}"`,
      "Content-Length": +filesrc.size
    })
    res.status(200);
    return new StreamableFile(file);
  }
  else {
    throw new HttpException('File not found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  }
} catch (err) {
  if (err.message) {
    throw new HttpException(err.message, err.status)
  }
  throw new HttpException(err, 500)
}
```

with this 'workaround' you can throw the error yourself and prevent the server from breaking.